# Need to Get Russian spellings with english sound

Tags: перевод

I need the spellings of two words "NEHA" and "RAJNI" as per Russian alphabets. I am residing in India, and these two words are Indian Names so I am also giving the sound details.

1. NEHA: "N" sounds Like "N" in "NAME", "E" sounds Like "E" in "NET" and "HA" sounds Like   "HA" in "HARD".
2. RAJNI: "R" sounds Like "R" in "RUB", "A" sounds Like "O" in "LOVE", "J" sounds Like "J" in "Jacket", "NI" sounds Like "NEE" in "NEED".

Please Help ASAP

Comment: It's Нэха Раджни

Comment: Неха or  Нэха which is correct and if both are correct then what is the diff in both. As I dont have any Idea of Russian alphabets and phonetics. Bye the way thanks a lot for the help. Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neha = Неха
Rajni = Раджни

I hope this helps.

Comment: Неха or  Нэха which is correct and if both are correct then what is the diff in both. As I dont have any Idea of Russian alphabets and phonetics. Bye the way thanks a lot for the help. Regards

Comment: Although this cannot be 100% standardised, Russian tends to convey the sound in question using ***e*** rather than ***э***. Thus *P**e**ggy* will be spelled *П**е**гги*, not *П**э**гги*, but the ***e*** will be pronounced pretty close to the original English sound.